# Batch modifying directory with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to update directory in many txt files

```
Input files:
1.txt
using c:\data\1.dta
its own data

2.txt
using c:\data\2.dta
its own data

3.txt
using c:\data\3.dta
its own data

Expected Output files:
1.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\1.dta
its own data

2.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\2.dta
its own data

3.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\3.dta
its own data
```

I've tried -replace but the results are strange: either all files have the same result or have all new directories (sell bellow)

I want to update the oldpath into the newpath in all files. The code is as following:

```
$pathway='C:Data\Subfile\*.txt'
$oldpath='c:\\data\\'
$newpath='C:\Data\Subfile\'
$content=Get-Content -path $pathway
```

Method 1:

```
$newline=((Get-Content -path $pathway -TotalCount 1) -replace $oldpath,$newpath)
$content[0]= $newline

This method will include all updated directories in every file:
Wrong output:
1.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\2.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\3.txt
its own data

2.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\2.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\3.txt
its own data
```

Method 2:

```
$content[0]=$content[0]-replace $oldpath,$newpath

This method will cause all file has the same new directory:
Wrong output:
1.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt 
its own data

2.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt 
its own data

3.txt
using C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt 
its own data

$content | Set-Content -Path $pathway
```

Can someone help me with that? I want each file has its corresponding new directory. For 1.txt I want C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt, for 2.txt I want C:\Data\Subfile\2.txt etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not clear to me what data you have, and what data you want. You say "*I want each file has its corresponding new directory. For 1.txt I want C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt, for 2.txt I want C:\Data\Subfile\2.txt etc.*" - but those don't have a corresponding new directory, they have the same directory. Can you edit into your question an example of how the data file looks before, and how you want it to look afterwards?

Comment: please add one [or three] sample input files & how you want each to be after the replacement.

Comment: Thank you @TessellatingHeckler, I've updated my question to make them clear! Actually, I want to update the same directory for all files instead of assigning different new directories for each of them.

Comment: Thank you  @Lee_Dailey, I've updated my question to make them clear! Actually, I want to update the same directory for all files instead of assigning different new directories for each of them.

Comment: @northernaland - that makes things a tad more clear - thanks! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on what you want the final content to be. Is it `using C:\Data\Subfile\1.txt` or `using C:\Data\Subfile\1.dta`? I think you are asking for the following but if not let me know. You may run into speed / performance issues depending on how large your files are.

If these are your input files with their content:

```
C:\data\Subfile\1.txt
  using c:\data\1.dta
  its own data...

C:\data\Subfile\2.txt
  using c:\data\2.dta
  its own data...

C:\data\Subfile\3.txt
  using c:\data\3.dta
  its own data...
```

then this:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\data\Subfile\*.txt | Foreach-Object{
    #Read in all content lines and replace c:\data\ with c:\data\subfile
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName | %{$_ -replace 'c:\\Data\\', 'c:\Data\Subfile\' }
    #write the new data to file
    $content | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

This results in the following:

```
C:\data\Subfile\1.txt
  using c:\Data\Subfile\1.dta
  its own data...

C:\data\Subfile\2.txt
  using c:\Data\Subfile\2.dta
  its own data...

C:\data\Subfile\3.txt
  using c:\Data\Subfile\3.dta
  its own data...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This script fits beginner like me most!

Answer (score 2):

With [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can precisely define where to insert text without repeating the search pattern.

```
foreach ($File in Get-ChildItem 'C:\Data\Subfile\*.txt'){
    (Get-Content $File -raw) -replace "(?<=C:\\data\\)(?=\d\.dta)","Subfile\" |
     Set-Content $File
}
```

- `"(?<=C:\\data\\)` is a positive lookbehind zero length assertion,
- `(?=\d\.dta)` is a positive lookahead zero length assertion,
- the replacement text is inserted in between these two.
- this is more secure than other approaches as it is repeatable without inserting `Subfile\` again.

Comment: That's a much better regex solution than mine. I'm curious what the lookbehind/ahead performance impact is like especially with large files?

Comment: @StephenP I think there **is** a penalty, not sure about the scale. I'll test it if I ever get some spare time- ;-)

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to do the job. [*grin*] what it does ...

- between the `#region/#endregion` markers is just to make the files to work with
- reads the list of files
- iterates thru that list
- loads the content of each one
- replaces the old dir with the new one
- finally writes out the new content

here's the code ...

```
#region - Make files to work with
$Null = New-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\TestFiles" -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$1stFileName = "$env:TEMP\TestFiles\1.txt"
$1stFileContent = @'
using c:\data\1.dta
its own data
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $1stFileName

$2ndFileName = "$env:TEMP\TestFiles\2.txt"
$2ndFileContent = @'
using c:\data\2.dta
its own data
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $2ndFileName

$3rdFileName = "$env:TEMP\TestFiles\3.txt"
@'
using c:\data\3.dta
its own data
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $3rdFileName
#endregion - Make files to work with

$OldDir = 'c:\data'
$NewDir = 'c:\data\SubDir'

$SourceDir = "$env:TEMP\TestFiles"

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter '*.txt' -File

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $NewContent = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Replace($OldDir, $NewDir)
            }
    $NewContent |
        Set-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
    }
```

content of file `1.txt` before & after the script runs ...

```
# before ...
using c:\data\1.dta
its own data    

# after ...
using c:\data\SubDir\1.dta
its own data
```